# SQLite table referring to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a table (contacts) and a table (connection) in SQLite, they are pretty self explanatory:

The contacts table holds information like id, firstname, secondname, and so on.
The connection table holds the id of a contact in one column, and the id of the contact it is connected with in another.

```
contacts

id | firstname | secondname
1  | test      | test
2  | asdf      | asdf
3  | qwer      | qwer

connection

id | contact_id | connection_to_id
1  | 1          | 2
2  | 1          | 3
```

How can I make the query to get the names one contact is connected with?
I tried it with this but it only gives me one name back, even if more are connected:

```
SELECT
    c.firstname, c.secondname
FROM contacts c
WHERE
    c.id =
    (SELECT
        scon.connection_to_id
    FROM connection scon
    WHERE
        scon.contact_id = 1)
```

I only get:

```
adsf asdf
```

But I want:

```
adsf asdf
qwer qwer
```

I hope you can understand my problem and help me with this :)

Comment: Is this SQLite or MySQL?  The subquery should return multiple rows, so you should use `WHERE c.id IN (SELECT....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest needs only a minor change, the `c.id =` to be changed into `c.id IN`:

```
SELECT
    c.firstname, c.secondname
FROM contacts c
WHERE
    c.id IN
    (SELECT
        scon.connection_to_id
    FROM connection scon
    WHERE
        scon.contact_id = 1) ;
```

You can also write with an `EXISTS` correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    c.firstname, c.secondname
FROM contacts c
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM connection scon
    WHERE
        scon.contact_id = 1
      AND 
        scon.connection_to_id = c.id) ;
```

or with a `JOIN` (as long as you don't have duplicate rows in the `connection` table):

```
SELECT
    c.firstname, c.secondname
FROM contacts c
  JOIN connection scon
    ON scon.connection_to_id = c.id
WHERE
    scon.contact_id = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE c.id IN (SELECT ...)`, that is, *IN* instead of =.